# Alter table with PHP and MySQL, add a column with an '@' sign

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check if a table has a certain column in it, and if not add that column to it. My code appears to work fine as long as the input value does not have an @ sign. I have tried surrounding 
'$email' 
with and without single quotes as an input string. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
$email = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']));
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `selections` LIKE '$email'",$conn);
$exists = (mysql_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;

if ($exists == FALSE) {
$query2 = "ALTER TABLE  selections ADD  $email VARCHAR( 120 ) NOT NULL";
$add= mysql_query($query2,$conn);
var_dump($query2);
echo("this error". mysql_error());
}
```

$query2 was taken directly from phpmyadmin and seems to work there even with an @ sign input

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by @ sign input?

Comment: Haha funky, its seems as though you are trying to store emails as columns and not rows...?? If so its a funky newbie mistake ;)

Answer (score 3):

Before anything else, please, **please** consider doing this in another way. You will be adding a field to a table for every email - what you probably do not know is that this increases the size of your table by increasing the size of the rows, and also limits you to a fixed number of fields ([This link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) clearly highlights a total of 65535 bytes per row max. Every VARCHAR character, depending on charset, is between 3 and 8 bytes)

The real reason why your request is failing is because `@` is a special character in your SQL queries and phpmyadmin happens to be smart enough to escape it. `@` denotes a variable in the SQL dialect uses by MySQL. You can either backtick-escape it for MySQL, or you can quit using this in favour of a table structure like this:

```
 selection:
  * id
  * your metadata here

 emails:
  * id
  * email_address

 selection_emails:
  * id
  * selection_id
  * email_id
```

The third table is called an associative table. It allows you to keep normalizing your data.

Comment: MySQL docs for valid naming: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the email with curly brackets `{$email}` to define it explicitly as a variable within a string, but you probably also need to escape odd characters in this variable before this.

When altering the table you should also surround this with back-ticks, to allow for odd characters.

The best approach would be to use **parameterized queries**, and drop the DEPRECATED mysql library. And also to not allow odd characters to be used in field names.

I would also question why you are adding email as a new column.